# Inheritance : How copy an object from master class to child class

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

In order to make an export, I need to overload an object in order to add a property which will transform a property from master class :

```
public class A
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; };
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; };
    /*...*/
    public myType MyPropertyN { get; set; };
}

public class B : A
{
    public override string MyProperty1
    {
        get :
        {
            return A.MyProperty1.ToString();
        }
        set :
        {
            a.MyProperty1 = int.parse(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is my A objects are already instantiated because the model come from the database.

I'm looking for a solution where I can do something like this :

```
var List<A> myListOfA = PopulateFromSomewhere();
var List<B> myListOfB = myListOfA.Select(x => new B(x)).ToList();
```

Where A will be copied in B and after call B in my export. I don't want to copy manually all properties of A in the constructor of B. Some objects have more than 20 properties.

Comment: Check out [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)

Comment: looks like you should'nt use inheritance in the first place, but just map one class to another one

Comment: I need to access to all another properties from A

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time changing the return-type from a class is a sign of a bad design. In particular it means that you should [favour composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#:%7E:text=To%20favor%20composition%20over%20inheritance,gives%20the%20design%20higher%20flexibility.&text=Initial%20design%20is%20simplified%20by,business-domain%20classes%20via%20inheritance.).

Having said this what you actuall want is to map one class to another. You can do that yourself, e.g. like this:

```
class A 
{ 
    int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
class B 
{
    private readonly A a;
    public B(A a) { this.a = a; }
}
```

Now you can easily implement your mapping:

```
class B
{
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get => this.a.MyProperty.ToString();
        set => { this.a.MyProperty = int.Parse(value); } // consider to check the value before conversion
    }
}
```

This is just the basic idea. As your models can become huge and doing this mapping yourself therefor becomes pretty cumbersome, you'd best use some automatic mapper, e.g. AutoMapper for that.